# How to force a page to refresh only once every visit

Tags: javascript, php

I've tried about 10 different ways that I found on here and the only found one that works close. I'm having an issue with Hostgator all of a sudden not displaying new content on php pages that access and display data from text files and/or databases. These pages have been in place for years working fine and continue to do so on other hosts. The only problem I have with the script below is that it won't refresh the page on the first visit. After the first refresh it will then show changes. I need something that will refresh all the time regardless of a visitors history or browser settings.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     (function()
     {
        if( window.localStorage ) {
           if( !localStorage.getItem( 'firstLoad' ) ) {
               localStorage[ 'firstLoad' ] = true;
               window.location.reload();
            }
          else
              localStorage.removeItem( 'firstLoad' );
        }
    })();

</script>
```

Comment: Removing any memory of having loaded the page sort of defeats the purpose of keeping track of it in the first place.

Comment: The ideal thing would be for Hostagtor to fix their issue. Instead they suggest using code as a bandaid. I tried META TAGs too. Has to be something out there to force a one time refresh on page load

Comment: You can also cut loose on Hostgator as there's way better options for hosting than that. Personally I find a simple, inexpensive VPS for scripted sites or things like [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) or [Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html) for static sites works very well.

Comment: Reloading on first load sounds like a crazy hack anyway. The only reason you'd need to reload in the first place is if you had some cached data stuck in your browser for some reason, which means any changes you make to try and defeat that are hidden because the old version is cached.

Comment: Just remove the `localStorage.removeItem( 'firstLoad' );` part

Comment: This script have no sense, specially the else part...

Comment: were are you `location.setItem` the item

Comment: I just tried removing that part of the code. No effect. I agree its a crazy hack. Even if I delete all my browser history, close the browser and reopen, I still see yesterdays data the first time I visit the page. All browsers too, not just IE or chrome. I don't have much knowledge in regard to the server end of things but its almost like it doesn't want to output the new data until its refreshed. They even cleared the cache on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a cookie:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

(function()
{
    var value = readCookie('mycookiereload');
    if(value == null)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(3600000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = "mycookiereload=1"+expires+"; path=/";
        alert("going to reload");
        window.location.reload();
    }
    else
    {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()-(3600000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = "mycookiereload="+expires+"; path=/";
        alert("kill cookie");
    }
})();
```

this will reload the page once. everytime you visit a page, it checks the cookie, if it's not there, creates and reloads, if it's there, removes the cookie to get the same effect again.